# MongoDB aggregation on documents with objects

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a MongoDB collection with documents that looks like this:

```
{
    'date': '2020-04-01', 
    'income': 1936.20, 
    'num_orders': 2.00,
    'avg_order_amount': 968.10
    'orders': [
        {
            'type': 'direct'
            'income': 1218.60, 
            'num_products': 3.00,
            'avg_product_price': 406.20
            'products': [ 
                { 
                    'name': 'product_1', 
                    'amount': 1.00
                }, 
                { 
                    'name': 'product_2', 
                    'amount': 2.00
                } 
            ] 
        },
        {
            'type': 'online'
            'income': 717.60, 
            'num_products': 4.00,
            'avg_product_price': 179.40
            'products': [ 
                { 
                    'name': 'product_2', 
                    'amount': 4.00
                } 
            ] 
        }
    ]
},
{
    'date': '2020-04-01', 
    'income': 2616.90, 
    'num_orders': 2.00,
    'avg_order_amount': 1308.45
    'orders': [
        {
            'type': 'direct'
            'income': 624.30, 
            'num_products': 2.00,
            'avg_product_price': 312.15
            'products': [  
                { 
                    'name': 'product_2', 
                    'amount': 2.00
                } 
            ] 
        },
        {
            'type': 'online'
            'income': 1992.6, 
            'num_products': 8.00,
            'avg_product_price': 249.08
            'products': [ 
                { 
                    'name': 'product_2', 
                    'amount': 4.00
                },
                { 
                    'name': 'product_3', 
                    'amount': 4.00
                } 
            ] 
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to get an aggregation that will result in something like this:

```
{
    'date': '2020-04-01', 
    'income': 4553.10, 
    'num_orders': 4.00,
    'avg_order_amount': 1138.28
    'orders': [
        {
            'type': 'direct'
            'income': 1842.9, 
            'num_products': 5.00,
            'avg_product_price': 368.58
            'products': [ 
                { 
                    'name': 'product_1', 
                    'amount': 1.00
                }, 
                { 
                    'name': 'product_2', 
                    'amount': 4.00
                } 
            ] 
        },
        {
            'type': 'online'
            'income': 2710.2, 
            'num_products': 12.00,
            'avg_product_price': 225.85
            'products': [ 
                { 
                    'name': 'product_2', 
                    'amount': 8.00
                },
                { 
                    'name': 'product_3', 
                    'amount': 4.00
                } 
            ] 
        }
    ]
}
```

Essentially I would like to be able to aggregate the income and then aggregate the documents inside the orders array, and inside that aggregate the documents inside products.

How can I accomplish that?

Thanks,